# validate controls in tab before switching to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript

I have 5 tabs in my tabcontainer. I want to validate the controls with in all the tabs.

Here I need to restrict the tab from switching to another tab if the validation is false for the current tab.
Here i copy the js that i have. but this is only for two tabs.

Can anyone help me here to make this code for 5 tabs ?

```
    function switchToTab(sender,args)

{

var tabContainer = $find(“<%= MainTabContainer.ClientID %>”);

var tab = $find(“<%= MainTabContainer.ClientID %>”).get_activeTabIndex();

switch (tab)

{

case 0:

if (Page_ClientValidate(‘tabPersonal’) == false)

{

$find(“<%= MainTabContainer.ClientID %>”).set_activeTabIndex(0);

$find(“<%= tabPersonal.ClientID %>”).set_activeTabIndex(0);

}

else if (Page_ClientValidate(‘tabContact’) == false)

{
$find(“<%= MainTabContainer.ClientID %>”).set_activeTabIndex(1);

$find(“<%= tabContact.ClientID %>”).set_activeTabIndex(0);

}

break;

case 1:

if (Page_ClientValidate(‘tabPersonal’) == false)

{

$find(“<%= MainTabContainer.ClientID %>”).set_activeTabIndex(0);

}

else if (Page_ClientValidate(‘tabContact’) == false)

{

$find(“<%= MainTabContainer.ClientID %>”).set_activeTabIndex(1);

$find(“<%= tabContact.ClientID %>”).set_activeTabIndex(0);

}

}

}
```

Comment: What technologies are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: If you are using the jquery validation plugin then apply `validate` to the form and every time a tab is clicked switch the tab only if `$("#form_id").valid() == true`.

Comment: I already have done the validation for the controls in the tab. but i dont know the validation code for restricting the tab from switching to another tab. I have got the js for that. but it does only for two tabs. I dont have much knowledge about js to edit it and make it to use for 5 tabs. Here i paste the js i have

Comment: I am working with ajax tab in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Use an UpdatePanel within the TabPanel. Write the validating code in the Event 'ActiveTabChanged' of the TabControl.

That is of course if you are using the AjaxControltoolkit.TabContainer control.

Comment: I already have done the validation for the controls in the tab. but i dont know the validation code for restricting the tab from switching to another tab